# Stacked bar chart using PHP

Tags: php, text, graph

I would like to create a stacked bar chart based on data from a text file USING PHP ... ( The file name must be on the x axis ... n based on the data read inside the file, y axis stack bars must be populated )

If you could provide me with code snippets and suggest the best libraries to use for this specific "dynamic stacked bar graph " creation, it'd be really helpful .

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What format is your data in?

I've used, and like [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net//) (The site has good examples).  There is a new version out but I have yet to use that.  They can do [stacked bar charts](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/screenshots.php?ID=18)

Fusion charts has both a free and paid version.  The paid version has [stacked bar charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/gallery/Category.asp?Stacked) (Not sure about the free) and they have examples on their site.

Both can be dynamic in generating graphs.  It really depends on your needs.

If it does not HAVE to be PHP there are javascript options that can read data from a file as well.

Comment: MY data is in a TXT file... THe name of that file has to be in the x axis and it's contents need to be stacked on y axis. However, the Y axis must have a STATIC granularity of 2 ... and the stacks must be inside this range of 2 .

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a broad question, and it seems like some Googling might be useful here.

That being said, I'd take a look at Highcharts.  It's a JavaScript library that draws graphs based on input data, which can easily be generated using PHP.

I currently use it with a Ruby on Rails app, and it works really well.

Comment: MY data is in a TXT file... THe name of that file has to be in the x axis and it's contents need to be stacked on y axis. However, the Y axis must have a STATIC granularity of 2 ... and the stacks must be inside this range of 2 . I ve been googling for 2 days and can't find something that satisfies my need/

Comment: PHP can extract all of that information out of a TXT file. Check [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP,_Filesystems_and_File_I/O) for how that works, got there through a Google of "PHP file i/o".  Then, when rendering the page that will be displaying the graphs, have it render javascript for the Highcharts library.